# Fail to login to SQL Server after disk migration

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 on my Win 7 os, everything works fine before the disk migration. But after cloning the whole disk then change my hard drive, I couldn't login using either Windows authentication or SQL Server authentication using `sa`.

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred...
>   Provider:named pipes provider
>   error:40-...microsoft sql server error:2

I checked the SQL Server configuration, TCP/IP, named pipes are all enabled. And I used windows administration account log in, user permission looks fine.

What else can I do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is SQL Browser service enabled?

Comment: maybe the service account doesn't have access to the binaries on the new disk.  I am betting the windows event log will have more info.  And verify the service is even started, as the error message you have looks like a connection error.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Are you logging in from the machine itself (locally) or from a different machine (remotely)? What are you using to connect? SSMS or some application? If it's an app, what's the connection string? NP error 2 means there is no NP listener on the target you're trying to connect to. That could be because you have a typo in your connection string instance name (if you have a named instance), NP is not enabled or the SQL Server is not running. Check the settings carefully from configuration manager. If you just enabled the protocol, you'll need to restart SQL Server for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thanks! I login locally using SSMS, I checked windows event log, it said"Error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.) occurred while opening file 'D:\Database\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary." I tried to mannually add master.mdf file to the folder which originally only has one agentsigningcertificate.cer file, it didnn't help, same error message.

Comment: Problem solved.It turns out that I lost bunch of files in the MSSQL folder. After I recovered them, the connection turns normal. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You can self-answer your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.It turns out that I lost bunch of files in the MSSQL folder. After I recovered them, the connection turns normal. Thanks everyone!